# how to expand or "zoom" pandas plot() figure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting with pandas plot() functions as follows:

In:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = subplots()
df['session_duration_seconds'].sort_index().value_counts().plot(figsize=(25,10), fontsize=24)
ax.legend(['session_duration_seconds'],fontsize=22)
ax.set_xlabel("Title", fontsize=22)
ax.set_ylabel("Title", fontsize=22)
ax.grid()
```

However, my plot looks very "behind" I would like to expand the plot in order to show in more detail the following section of the figure:

Out:

[image]

Thus, my question is how can I expand or getting more close with pandas plot over that portion of the image?

Comment: Are you trying to view it in Jupyter inline or an IDE and save the file?

Comment: essentially two options: 1. rescale the axes. 2. use ylim, set it maybe to 100, then you will lose just few information but get more detail for the other values

Comment: A standard way to zoom your plot would be to screen your data before plotting like: `df.loc[df['session_duration_seconds']<200]`

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 could you provide an example?

Comment: @Chris im in jupyter

Comment: @ysearka could you provide an example too?

Comment: @anon In order for people to provide examples, you should consider adding a sample of data in your question, making it easier for others to answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an example to show how this could work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': [1000, 1, 2, 3 , 4 , 2, 5]})
df.plot()
```

[image]

Now let's restrict the y-range

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.plot()
plt.ylim(0, 10)
```

[image]

and we see the details of the curve.

Note that the curve is so steep near 0 due to the huge slope induced by the first y-value of 1000.

Also you can just scale the y-axis directly form within pandas plot functions:

```
df.plot(logy=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: To obtain more detail, just scale the y-axis. See my edited answer below. However, this will not be the zoom you would like to have. But I'd assume that this is not possible within matplotlib. Potentially, one would need some kind of java script or so